# How to append PBS job output to log files instead of overwriting it?

Tags: pbs, torque

I'm using Torque and I want my PBS log+error output to be appended to previous log/error file instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this as a separate step in the job script. 

`cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
mkdir $PBS_JOBID
mycode 1> $PBS_JOBID/myoutput.out 2> $PBS_JOBID/myerror.err
cat $PBS_JOBID/myoutput.out >> previouslogoutput.out`

Comment: Hi. Sorry but my Torque setup is actually appending by default instead of overwriting but I don't know what the previous sysadmin did. I was wondering what was the step so that I could reverse it.

Comment: check prologue/eplilogue scripts to see if there is anything there. How does it append? When you run a new job where does the output file go now?